# How to add types of markers to the map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, markers

I am looking for example of how to add markers of different type (different images) using OpenLayers 3.

This is my code:

```
iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image : new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor : [ 0.5, 46 ],
                anchorXUnits : 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits : 'pixels',
                opacity : 0.75,
                src : '/icon.png'
            }))
        });
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features : []
        })
vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source : vectorSource,
            style : iconStyle
        });
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I can't seem to have more than one icon. For example if user clicks on map, marker from one source is displayed, and when he enters an address, a marker form another source is displayed.

How this should be managed? Do I nee to create multiple iconStyle, vectorSource and many vectorLayer attached to map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a separate icon style for each style you want to display.  It helps to have them all in a reference cache so you don't create a separate style for each object (see the `styles` object in the code below.

Then, when adding a feature to a layer you need to reference the style from the cache which matches the feature type you're adding.

Please check the example below and try to integrate it into your code:

```
var styles = [];
var features = [];

/*
 * data is a JSON object from web API that looks like this:
 * 

    var data = [{
      markerClass: "blue",
      code: "water",
      lat: 0, // no really, but you get the idea
      lng: 0
    }, {
      etc...
    }]

 *
 */

$.each(data, function (i, item) {

  // Check style cache for already created style
  if (!styles[item.markerClass]) {
    // In your case you will want to use  image : new ol.style.Icon(({
    // but this is the example that I have on hand..
    styles[item.markerClass] = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#000'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: item.markerClass // attribute colour
        })
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: item.code, // attribute code
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: "#000" // black text // TODO: Unless circle is dark, then white..
        })
      })
    });
  }

  // Create the feature
  var marker = new ol.Feature({
    content: item,
    mapid: i,
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
      ol.proj.transform(
        [item.lng, item.lat], 
        proj_out, proj_in)
      )
  });

  // Set style created earlier
  marker.setStyle(styles[item.markerClass]);

  features.push(marker);

});

// Assuming your layer / source is already map bound
var source = layer.getSource();
source.addFeatures(features);
```